# StatusBar text fade-out when binding using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In my `ShellViewModel` I have the following property:

```
private string _status = "";
public string Status
{
    get
    {
        return _status;
    }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Status);
    }
}
```

In the ShellView I've named my StatusBar TextBlock "Status" so that it binds to the above using `Caliburn.Micro` - and it does.

Then I've tried to add a "StoryBoard" element so that after a short amount of time the text fades away - currently the text appears but does not fade away - how do I fix this?

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">

  <TextBlock x:Name="Status">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                              Duration="0:0:0"
                              To="1.0" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                              Duration="0:0:2"
                              From="1.0"
                              To="0.0"
                              BeginTime="0:0:5" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
  </TextBlock>

</StatusBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two changes,

First, you need to update the binding to Raise the TargetUpdated Event when property changes. This can be done using [Binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.notifyontargetupdated?view=netframework-4.8)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
```

Then, your `BeginTime` is higher than the `Duration` in the second animation (BeginTime="0:0:5" ), which needs to be corrected.

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                              Duration="0:0:2" From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:0.5" />
```

Complete Code

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Status, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
                <TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                              Duration="0:0:0" To="1.0" BeginTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                              Duration="0:0:2" From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
   </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Anu: learning as I go! So from what you are saying Duration is the total time of the animation e.g. 5 seconds, and BiginTime is then within the Duration period ... so I was trying to start the effect when the animation had already finished?

Comment: 1 more question: do I need two DoubleAnimation elements? Is the first DoubleAnimation element redundant?

Comment: @whytheq that's true. you need to set the BeginTime within the duration. Regarding two double animations, i do not think you need two animations in this particular case. In case you want to Fade In followed by FadeOut, you could make use of 2 animations.

Comment: Thanks again Anu - you are a gentleman for your patience ... I am an eager newbie of `WPF` so asking many naive questions. I will check your solution tomorrow when I have access to the project and mark this as the correct answer if it works. I worry slightly that the automatic binding via Caliburn might somehow interfere with this binding for the animation... but hopefully all will be good.

Comment: @whytheq Glad to help you.